# What does the `--` value mean in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I found that in some other people's data, the value "--" sometimes appear in an numpy array. How to set an array element to be "--" ?

something like this:

```
[-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 0.27969929575920105 0.27994874119758606
 0.27715885639190674 0.26716524362564087 0.2594984173774719
 0.2584466338157654 0.2565436065196991 0.2539260685443878
 0.2531115710735321 0.25570642948150635 0.2644173204898834
 0.26860886812210083]
```

Comment: You will have to show an example of how you get these.

Comment: Did you try getting one of those items by index. `x = arr[0]; print(repr(x), type(x), help(x))`

Comment: Looks like a [masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/maskedarray.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a NumPy "[masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/maskedarray.html)."  It carries with it an array of booleans, and where they are True the data is understood to be invalid--and hence printed as `--`.

If you want to see the masked data, it's accessible using the `.data` property of the masked array (which of course you can print).